# $9$ homeomorphism classes of topology on $3$ element set. $8$ have names, what about the $9^{th}$?

Tags: general-topology

It's a popular introductory exercise in a topology course to enumerate the topologies on a $3$-element set. ($2$ elements is trivial, $4$ elements is laborious.)

The answer is of course $29$.

These $29$ are known to be classified into $9$ homeomorphism classes, $8$ of which are instances of specific topology types as documented in Steen and Seebach's "Counterexamples in Topology" (yes I know, I've cited it before, it's one of my favourite books).

Thus for a set $S = \{a, b, c\}$ examples of each of those types are as follows.

$1$: Indiscrete topology: $\{\varnothing, S\}$

$2$: Discrete topology: $\{\varnothing, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\}, S\}$

$3$: Included set topology: $\{\varnothing, \{a, b\}, S\}$ (where here the included set is $\{a, b\}$)

$4$: Excluded Set topology: $\{\varnothing, \{a\}, S\}$ (where here the excluded set is $\{b, c\}$)

$5$: Partition topology: $\{\varnothing, \{a\}, \{b, c\}, S\}$

$6$: Order toplogy: $\{\varnothing, \{a\}, \{a, b\}, S\}$ (where here the order is $a \preccurlyeq b \preccurlyeq c$)

$7$: Particular point topology: $\{\varnothing, \{a\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, S\}$ (where here the particular point is $a$)

$8$: Excluded point topology: $\{\varnothing, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a, b\}, S\}$ (where here the excluded point is $c$)

... and then the $9^{th}$ equivalence class, exemplified by:

$\{\varnothing, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, S\}$

Does this class of topology have a name? If not, does that mean there is another class of topology which has not been explicitly documented in Steen & Seebach which may merit a separate entry?

(And ultimately: has the task of classification of finite topologies been exhaustively completed in the same way as finite groups? And if the answer to that is no: is this a fruitful topic to select as a research project with a view to making it the basis for a PhD or MSc or whatever?)

Comment: I am unaware of a specific name for 9th topology. As for your ultimate question, the answer is "no" and "hell, no." It would be akin to a "classification" of all finite graphs. The main reason for the exercise is pedagogical: For students to develop a degree of understanding of non-metric topologies.